# Is it possible to connect to FEMA's WMS and WFS using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, wfs

I have just found out about the wonderful world of WMS and WFS. I have added the FEMA versions of both to QGIS. [WMS](https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/services/public/NFHLWMS/MapServer/WMSServer?) and [WFS](https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/WFSServer). The WMS seems to connect and adds something to QGIS, yet it is not visible. The WFS connects, but I get an error that it is not a valid layer.

So... I guess that my question is - Is anyone willing to test these and maybe give some guidance on how to better use these?

I have also tried NYS [WMS](http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/ArcGIS/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer?) and the Nationwide Inventory WMS `http://107.20.228.18/ArcGIS/services/FWS_Wetlands_WMS/mapserver/wmsserver?` with no luck. Similar results to FEMA's WMS.

Comment: I'm getting same thing for WMS. In Properties>General tab: Columns, Rows and No-Data Value are all n/a.

Comment: The webserver on the first link isn't working. And the service in the second link doesn't have WMS capability enabled.

Comment: The link above for FEMA worked for me in v2.0.1.  What version are you using?

Comment: The FEMA WMS and WFS links work for me in v2.0.1. The Nationwide Inventory WMS link connects, but the resulting layer is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are scale dependent. Some do not show unless you are zoomed way in.

Comment: you're right. Though in my case, I was zoomed so far in, it looked like there was nothing there - it was all one color, as if no data had loaded.